# Functions die() and exit() have no effect on PHP74

Tags: php, centos

I  installed PHP74 and some libraries on my CentOS 7:

```
libicu71-71.1-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm libsodium-1.0.18-1.el7.x86_64.rpm php-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-bcmath-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-cli-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-common-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-devel-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-gd-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-intl-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-json-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-mbstring-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-mysqlnd-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-opcache-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-pdo-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-pecl-mcrypt-1.0.5-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64.rpm php-pecl-solr2-2.6.0-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64.rpm php-pecl-zip-1.21.1-1.el7.remi.7.4.x86_64.rpm php-pgsql-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-process-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-soap-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-sodium-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-tidy-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-xml-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm php-xmlrpc-7.4.33-2.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm postgresql-libs-9.2.24-8.el7_9.x86_64.rpm
```

after that I have these warnings:
PHP Warning:

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8' (tried: /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8 (/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/oci8.so (libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_oci' (tried: /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci (/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_oci.so (libclntsh.so.21.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'rdkafka.so' (tried: /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/rdkafka.so (/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/rdkafka.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/rdkafka.so.so (/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/rdkafka.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0 
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'zmq' (tried: /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zmq (/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zmq: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zmq.so (libzmq.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

and functions `die()` and `exit()` have no effect, only `return` works properly.

I tried to find `libclntsh.so` as it said that that lib imports some libraries from warnings but there is no such file on my machine

Comment: I did test in a php 7.4 docker image and both functions were doing as expected. Can you show us the code you've used on your tests?

Comment: As you didnt appear to load the Oracle extension, did you check that the `php.ini` file has the `oci8` extension commented out?

Comment: I am at a loss as to why you report an error with a Ocacle extension and then talk about the `exit` and `die` functions? I dont see what the 2 have to do with each other

Comment: Please post list of installed packages (rpm -qa php\*) and enabled extensions (php -m)

Comment: For oci8 ext and missing libclntsh.so.21.1, see https://blog.remirepo.net/post/2020/05/18/Installation-of-Oracle-extensions-for-PHP

Comment: Please share the code involved to reproduce the problem

Answer (score 1):

Okay, guys, the problem was in uopz module. I disabled it and everything works as expected